# ООП и функции в C++

Tags: ооп, c++

Необходимо реализовать такой механизм в C++:

1. передать в процедуру ссылку на форму (Form);
2. в этой процедуре создать кучу (в смысле много)) визуальных объектов (или даже массивов объектов), принадлежащих этой форме (типа pictureBox, button и т. д.); впоследствии планируется сохранить ссылки на эти объекты для последующей с ними работы.

Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Пытаюсь вот так:

```
class FormObjects { // класс, хранящий объекты, принадлежащие форме приложения  
public: // хочу хранить массив изображений   
    //(не знаю, как динамически загрузить изображение)  
    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pb[100];  
    // процедура получает ссылку на форму  
    // и должна инициализировать изображение  
    void Init(System::Windows::Forms::Form^ form){
    }  
};
```

пишет

> собственный массив не может содержать этот управляемый тип, Вы имели в виду `"array<System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox ^>"`?

а если без [100] - один объект, то

> `error C3265: нельзя объявлять управляемый "pb" в неуправляемом "FormObjects"`
> Может не объявлять глобальную или статичную переменную или элемент собственного типа, который относится к объекту в куче сборщика мусора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передать в функцию указатель на форму. Вот некий прототип её. Т.е. небольшое приближение. функция.

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunction( cForm* form )
{
  but = new cButton( "Кнопка" );
  form->addButton( but );
  ....
  form->addpictureBox(...);
}
```

Если Вам нужно сохранить ссылки на добавленные контролы. То наверное лучше в классе 
SomeClass хранить указатели на них.
....

```
 SomeClass
 {
  private:
    cButton* but;

    cPictureBox* pb;

 };
```

Comment: сделал. Пишет, что не видит ни cForm, ни cButton, ни addButton.
может я не подключил что-нибудь?

Comment: Эти названия классов были указаны просто для примера. Укажите свои классы. Подумайте хоть немного сами.

Comment: Сорри, забыл написать, что работаю в Visual Studio 2010

Comment: MFC?

Comment: С какой GUI-вской библиотекой работаете? MFC? То, что я написал - это просто пример, набросок, покажите конкретный код. В вопрос добавьте.